# Pivot rows into columns with fixed rows but unknown content in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I've seen lots of questions relating to pivoting rows into columns, but nothing similar enough to my problem to make any headway with it.

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
| candidate | qualification | unit | passed |
---------------------------------------------
| C1        | Q1            | U1-1 | 1      |
| C1        | Q1            | U1-2 | 1      |
| C1        | Q2            | U2-1 | 0      |
| C1        | Q2            | U2-2 | 1      |
| C2        | Q1            | U1-1 | 0      |
| C2        | Q1            | U1-2 | 0      |
| C2        | Q2            | U2-1 | 1      |
| C2        | Q2            | U2-2 | 1      |
```

where each candidate can be signed up to multiple qualifications, which each have multiple units that can be passed (1) or failed (0).

I need the data to be transformed to look like:

```
| candidate | qualification | unit_1 | unit_1_passed | unit_2 | unit_2_passed |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| C1        | Q1            | U1-1   | 1             | U1-2   | 1             |
| C1        | Q2            | U2-1   | 0             | U2-2   | 1             |
| C2        | Q1            | U1-1   | 0             | U1-2   | 0             |
| C2        | Q2            | U2-1   | 1             | U2-2   | 1             |
```

so that the unit for each qualification and if is passed is pivoted into a column.

I know that there will always be **fixed number of units per qualification**, but **I do not know what the unit names will be in advance**.

My query currently looks like:

```
select
  candidate,
  qualification,
  unit,
  passed
from exams
```

but I don't know how to go about pivoting the rows into columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function row_number() to assign a rank to each unit in each candidate/qualification group, and then pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select
    candidate,
    qualification,
    max(case when rn = 1 then unit end) unit_1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then passed end) unit_1_passed,
    max(case when rn = 2 then unit end) unit_2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then passed end) unit_2_passed
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by candidate, qualification 
            order by unit
        ) rn
    from exams t
) t
group by candidate, qualification
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with

```
select 'C1' as 'candidate', 'Q1' as 'qualification', 'U1-1' as 'unit', '1' as 'passed'  into #tmp union
select 'C1', 'Q1', 'U1-2', '1' union
select 'C1', 'Q2', 'U2-1', '0' union
select 'C1', 'Q2', 'U2-2', '1' union
select 'C2', 'Q1', 'U1-1', '0' union
select 'C2', 'Q1', 'U1-2', '0' union
select 'C2', 'Q2', 'U2-1', '1' union
select 'C2', 'Q2', 'U2-2', '1' 


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@colsUnit AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select * from #tmp

DECLARE @UnitNames VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @UnitNames = COALESCE(@UnitNames + ', ', '') + 'unit_' +unitnumber 
FROM (select distinct right(unit,1) unitnumber from #tmp)a


select candidate, unit, qualification, passed, 'unit_'+b.unitnumber as unitnumber into #tmp2 from #tmp a
inner join (select distinct right(unit,1) unitnumber from #tmp) b on right(a.unit,1) = b.unitnumber
where right(unit,1) = unitnumber
order by unitnumber

select * from #tmp2 order by unitnumber


SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.unitnumber) 
            FROM #tmp2 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @colsUnit = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.unitnumber) 
            FROM #tmp2 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT candidate, qualification, unit, 
                ' + @colsUnit + ' from 
            (
                select candidate
                    , qualification
                    , passed
                    , unit
                    , unitnumber
                from #tmp2
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(passed)
                for unitnumber in (' + @colsUnit + ')
            ) p '


print @query

exec (@query)

drop table #tmp, #tmp2
```

It yields a table kinda close to yours:

[image]
Hope it helps